# Trim whitespace around a transparent PNG

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So, I've managed to get myself stuck in a situation where a database full of images ( transparent images of various products ) needs to be placed on the stage, all of which need to be aligned the same by the products height.

My problem is that the png's of products are 'floating' and I have no control of where about's in the png it will sit ( could be tight at the top and loads of room at the bottom, vice versa)

Does anyone know an existing way to find out the png's 'true' height ( width is an extra ). I've thought about looping through the bitmap data and checking but wondered if anyone has invented this wheel already?

eg [Example with room at top](http://cl.ly/2wdQ) / [Example with none, really](http://cl.ly/2wSe)

Comment: interesting question - I think looping both directions is your best bet

Comment: Yeah, Im just confident that I can't be the first person to need a bi-directional transparency checker. But if not, I'll go ahead and have a play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I eventually came to was the below, most likely not the most performant way but it works.

```
    /**
     * Cuts off the transparency around a bitmap, returning the true width and height whilst retaining transparency
     *  
     * @param input Bitmap
     * 
     */
    private function trimTransparency(input:BitmapData,colourChecker:uint = 0x00FF00):Bitmap {

        //Keep a copy of the original
        var orignal:Bitmap = new Bitmap(input);

        //Clone the orignal with a white background
        var clone:BitmapData = new BitmapData(orignal.width, orignal.height,true,colourChecker);
        clone.draw(orignal);

        //Grab the bounds of the clone checking against white
        var bounds:Rectangle = clone.getColorBoundsRect(colourChecker, colourChecker, false);

        //Create a new bitmap to return the changed bitmap
        var returnedBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
        returnedBitmap.bitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height,true,0x00000000);
        returnedBitmap.bitmapData.copyPixels(orignal.bitmapData,bounds, new Point(0,0));    
        return returnedBitmap;


    }
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use the method of the BitmapData class getColorBoundsRect() to get the rectangle of non-transparent content. The documentation gives this example too:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Thanks,
Alistair

Answer (score 3):

As Alistair says, the getColorBoundsRect will ultimately be your best option.

I haven't looked into it too much, but I'm not sure if getColorBoundsRect allows you to "select all non 100% alpha-ed pixels". If it doesn't you can easily use the BitmapData.threshold method to get you to that stage.

I'd do something like duplicate the bitmap, run the threshold method on it turning all non alpha-ed pixels bright green, then run getColorBoundsRect selecting all the green pixels you just created.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, posted my solution which follows the same theme as your's but without out the threshold. Turns out you can just replace the background then run getColorBoundsRect on the negative white space.

Comment: I would avoid using white as your background fill... what would happen if you had an image with a white border?

Comment: True a white border would mess this up bigstyle. hmmm, I'll look further in to it, maybe have next to the input another var for the colour fill defaulting to green. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I came up with, in case anyone needs:

```
    public static function trimAlpha(source:BitmapData):BitmapData {
        var notAlphaBounds:Rectangle = source.getColorBoundsRect(0xFF000000, 0x00000000, false);
        var trimed:BitmapData = new BitmapData(notAlphaBounds.width, notAlphaBounds.height, true, 0x00000000);
        trimed.copyPixels(source, notAlphaBounds, new Point());
        return trimed;  
    }
```